# Поле input javascript

Tags: javascript

Не получается добавить блок до или после поля input

```
    var qw = document.getElementByTagName("input");

       var newItem = document.createElement("div");
    newItem.innerHTML = "TEXT YEXT";

    qw.insertBefore(newItem, qw);
```

В чем может быть косяк?

Answer (score 1):

Косяк в том, что метода getElementByTagName не существует.
Есть метод **getElementsByTagName**, но и он в данном случае не сработает.
Делать надо так:

```
var qw = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
 //[0] отдаст первый элемент, так как getElementsByTagName возвращает коллекцию
   var newItem = document.createElement("div");
newItem.innerHTML = "TEXT YEXT";
//к тому же, добавлять надо в родителя:
var parent = qw.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(newItem, qw);
```